# How do I get the full query for "Edit top 200 rows" in SSMS that I can copy to a word document?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

I am working in SQL Server 2016. I need to get the script "version" of "Edit top 200 rows". I know it will be pretty much the same as INSERT but does anyone know of a way to view the script? Similar to Scripting a Table.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The "Edit top n rows" opens a UI, not a query window. It's not "similar to scripting a table", it's similar to scripting a web browser.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I must have explained it wrong. I am trying to get a query script from the UI. For instance, if I manually add 30 rows and I want to see the script for it. I am very new to SQL

Comment: You want to see the script for what? I don't think this question is very clear because you aren't really sure what you want.

Comment: Basically, the "output" from the UI. The code that the UI will output

Comment: Again, what's the end goal here? What will your caption say under this theoretical script in the Word document?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to script your changes in the edit top n rows UI like you can from many dialog boxes in SSMS. It all happens behind the scenes.

You could get fancy and run a trace to see what's being executed, but this might be more than you need?

I suspect what you are trying to do/see is either an INSERT or an UPDATE statement(s). There are lots of tutorials and examples of how to do this on the internet, or in SSMS if you right click on the table > script table as > INSERT to or UPDATE to will give you a script to start with.

Comment: Does this give you what you need?

Comment: It does yes. Thank you

Comment: @EtienneSwart, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: I would love to but I need 15 rep to be able to do that. This is my first post so I don't have enough rep unfortunately.

Comment: @EtienneSwart, the 15 rep is for up voting (clicking on the arrows around the number in the upper left). There is no reputation requirement for accepting the answer (clicking on the grey check mark right underneath that).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in SSMS there is a button in the tool bar for this exact purpose. Click the button circled in red to see the query. Click the button circled in blue to execute the query.  I believe it is part of the designer suite in SSMS so that might explain its independence from where you regularly build and execute queries.
[image]